# Is it possible to access fields of event during logstash scripted_upsert?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-painless

Is it possible to access event fields in script of elasticsearch logstash output with scripted_upsert?

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "index"
        document_type => "doctype"
        action => "update"
        document_id => "%{some_field}"
        scripted_upsert => true
        script => 'ctx._source.name = event["some_field"];'
        script_var_name => "event"
        script_type => "inline"
    }
}
```

If I use such script it does not upsert document. But if I set `ctx._source.name` to something static. For example.

`script => 'ctx._source.name = "something"'`

It works as expected. And upserts document.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ctx._source.name = params.event.get("some_field")
```